# for/in loop help, and help understanding

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, for-in-loop

I'm currently following a tutorial that uses BeautifulSoup to extract information from an HTML page, and while I was following, I realized I didn't understand a step. The code is:

```
period_tags = seven_day.select(".tombstone-container .period-name")
periods = [pt.get_text() for pt in period_tags]
periods
```

I'm confused by the second line. I understand brackets are used for lists, but I don't understand where the "pt" came from, and I'm also fairly unfamiliar with the "for" and "in".

Could someone help me understand? Hopefully I provided enough context.

Comment: Please format your code in the future with four spaces in front of the line, instead of `>` (which indicates a quote)

Answer (score 3):

It's called a *list comprehension*. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

It's like an inverted for-loop, which allows you to create lists from an iterable (and, optionally, a condition). Quoting the documentation example, if you want to create a list of squares of numbers < 10, the standard way to do it, would be

```
squares = []
for x in range(10):
    squares.append(x**2)
```

But the list comprehension syntax allows you to write

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

or, just the even numbers

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10) if x%2==0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment and link! I think I understand now

Comment: @hntrandrew You should probably spend some time working through the official Python tutorial that blue_note linked. It will make it easier for you to understand the BeautifulSoup tutorial. Also see [What tutorial should I read?](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F)

Comment: @hntrandrew: thanks, please accept answer if that helped